# How to Show Outlook Ribbon on multiple tabs c#

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, ribbon

I am developing an Outlook plugin. I have added a ribbon with the ribbon type set to

```
this.RibbonType = "Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer";
```

and `ControlId` is set to `TabMail`. By default this ribbon shows on the Home tab in Outlook. But when I open an email in a separate window, when I switch to a different tab or when I view attachments, the ribbon does not appear. I also want to show this ribbon on the Message tab and the Attachments tab.

I have explored ways and got answers that refer to creating two ribbons, but that is not a proper solution.

I also followed [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/71e1fb1e-219b-4412-b0f0-367a8db72151/how-to-add-group-to-an-existing-outlook-inspector-ribbon?forum=vsto), but with no luck.

The other solution i explored is to call event `tabControl_SelectedIndexChanged` on tabs to identify the current tab and then setting ribbon properties(ribbontype and ribbon control) run time.
How to do that for ribbon (Visual Designer)? Or I have to convert that into ribbon (xml)? And where to trigger that event?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new Ribbon with ribbonType Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Read and your controlId TabReadMessage

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose appropriate values for the RibbonType property:

[image]

you can select such

- List item
  Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Compose or
  Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Read